# Is $f:\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)\rightarrow \mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$, $f(A)=A^c$ (complement, $A^c=\mathbb Z\setminus A$) injective\surjective?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$f:\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)\rightarrow \mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$, $f(A)=A^c$ (complement, $A^c=\mathbb Z\setminus A$).

Hello everyone. I am having a little trouble with proving whether or not this function is injective and/or surjective. I would appreciate some hints to get started. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Well, this function is self-inverse, i.e.,  $f\circ f = id$, since $(A^c)^c=A$. This means that $f$ is both injective and surjective.

Comment: Thank you. My teacher introduced us using schemes so I was trying to prove this by showing that if f(A)=f(B) and A=B then f is injective and for surjective, I have to show that it f(A)=B for some B in the codomain. I didn't think to use inverses.

Answer (score 2):

A direct proof:

surjective: if $B\in\mathcal P(\Bbb Z)$ (codomain), this comes from $A:=B^c$, that is
$$
f(A)=f(B^c)=\Bbb Z\setminus (B^c)=\Bbb Z\setminus(\Bbb Z\setminus B)=B.
$$

injective: given $A_1,A_2\in\mathcal P(\Bbb Z)$ (domain) such that $f(A_1)=f(A_2)$, that is $\Bbb Z\setminus A_1=\Bbb Z\setminus A_2$, you immediately can see that this is equivalent to $A_1=A_2$.

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn't have thought to assume $A=B^c$ when proving surjective.